# Reaction of 1 equivalent of Mg in ether with 1,4-dibromobut-2-yne

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent

What will be the product formed the if the reaction of Mg in ether with 1,4-dibromobut-2-yne occurs? At first, I thought the answer would be cyclobutyne, but the correct answer is buta-1,2,3-triene.

Can anyone please explain how?

Comment: Cyclobutyne cannot exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cyclobutyne cannot exist.  There is no way to enforce 90° bends at both ends of a triple bond, but the carbanion formed by the Grignard reagent synthesis finds an easy way around this problem.

Let's say the magnesium reacts at position 1.  Then the negative charge would couple with the conjugated triple bond to spread to position 3:

$\ce{Br\overset{+}{Mg}\overset{-}{C}H2-C#C-CH2Br <-> Br\overset{+}{Mg}CH2=C=\overset{-}{C}-CH2Br}$

Then the carbon atom at position 3 can act as a nucleophile, displacing the remaining bromine as a bromide ion to give the product named in the book.

Comment: Sorry, I've noticed you've been struggling with formatting for a while and IMO it's visually better to put charges *above* with `\overset{<above>}{<below>}` command so that the skeletal structure is preserved – it's then arguably easier to visually compare both structures, like so (you can right-click on the formula and select *Show Math As → TeX Commands*): $$\ce{Br\overset{\large +}{Mg}-\overset{\large -}{C}H2-C#C-CH2Br <-> Br\overset{\large +}{Mg}-CH2=C=\overset{\large -}{C}-CH2Br}$$ Just a suggestion:)

Comment: Does not make sense. The Mg-R bond is part of the anion there is no free electron pair. Too many pentavalent carbons. Experimental details to this synthesis would help out.

Comment: I do not understand. Where are the pentavalent carbons? Are you saying neither of the two pi bonds is in plane with the anionic center electron pair to undergo conjugation? Please offer an alternative answer.

Comment: Sorry I confused the typing  The possible sigma bond to the Mg does not seem likely to be in resonance with the triple bond the unanswered question, Does this reaction really happen?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that these type of questions have been found in IIT-JEE entrance examination books, which are mostly written by authors who have not thought well before preparing the question. Before creating  a new question, the author has to look for experimental evidence. Chemistry is not mathematical science, where you can extrapolate and find a solution to question.

Coming to your question, it seems theoretical. If I assert that  buta-1,2,3-triene would form, then it becomes a precedent and  a novice chemistry researcher would try hard to make the same compound.

As I  have not come across any textbook or reference discussing this type of reactions,  answering the question would be inappropriate at this time.

I will update the answer if I come across any reference.

Comment: The internet offers no info; what is there is fraught with misstatements. Grignards are reducing agents not oxidizers  so the cumulated  triene is difficult to predict unless bimolecular. Perhaps cyclobutene?