# Conversion reaction - Organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]
I tried solving this problem, but my answer doesn't match with any of the given options. Here's my solution.
[image]

Comment: You seem to be asking a lot of questions from a particular book (MS Chouhan). Do you know that there is a solution manual provided with the book?

Comment: Yes. But this is the NEET version. I don't think it comes with a solution manual :(

Comment: What else can happen after the first Grignard is made?

Answer (score 1):

Your final product will decompose to form cyclopropane.

$$\ce{Br-(CH2)_3-Br + 2 Mg ->[ether] BrMg-(CH2)_3-MgBr -> (\Delta)  + other side product}$$

See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114489/what-will-form-when-dihalides-or-trihalides-or-polyhalides-react-with-magnesium/114510#114510) for more details.